# Limit of hypergeometric function in proof of Gauss's summation formula

Tags: limits, special-functions, gamma-function

I've been studying special functions from Askey,Roy and in proof of Gauss's summation formula (theorem 2.2.2) it states that
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\Gamma (c+n-a)\Gamma(c+n-b)}{\Gamma (c+n) \Gamma(c+n-a-b)}\  _2F_1(a,b;c+n;1)=1$.
Only thing we know about $a,b,c$ is that $Re(c-a-b)>0$

I dont understand how is that correct. I have tryed using $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma (n+a)}{\Gamma(n)n^a}=1$ but I dont know what to do with hypergeometric function.

Comment: You can show that you can take the termwise limit of the hypergeometric series.

Comment: I thought of it but I dont see how it helps. When I represent it as series there is $n$ only in denominator and when $n \to \infty$ we have that terms goes to $0$. Can you correct me or write it in more details?

Comment: All the terms go to zero, except for the first one.